# Linear programming if/then modification to cost function?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I'm setting up a linear programming optimization model using CPLEX and am wondering if it's possible to accomplish a modification of the cost function dependent upon which binary decision variables are 'active' in an arbitrary solution. This is mostly a question about how to formulate the LP model (if it's even possible), but responses in the context of CPLEX are welcome or even preferred.

Say I have an LP problem in canonical form:

```
minimize cTx
s.t. Ax <= b
```

With cost function:

```
c = [c_1, c_2,...,c_100]
```

All variables are binary. I have this basic setup modeled and running effectively in CPLEX.

Now say I have a subset of variables:

```
efficiency_set = [x_1, x_2,...,x_5]
```

With the condition:

```
if any x_n in efficiency_set == 1
then c_n for all other x_n in the set = 0.9 * c_n
```

Essentially there is a dependency where if any x_n in the efficiency set is 'active', it becomes 10% less expensive for other variables in the set to appear in the solution.

I thought that CPLEX indicator constraints were what I was looking for, but after reading through documentation, I don't think I can enforce an on-the-fly change to cost function with them (I could be wrong).  So I feel like it needs to be done through formulation of the LP, but I can't reason how to accomplish it. Any ideas?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPLEX you have many APIs, let me answer you with the easiest one OPL.

Your canonical form can be written

```
int n=3;
int m=4;

range N=1..n;
range M=1..m;

float A[N][M]=[[1,4,9,6],[8,5,0,8],[2,9,0,2]];
float B[M]=[3,1,3,0];
float C[N]=[1,1,1];

dvar boolean x[N];

minimize sum(i in N) C[i]*x[i];

subject to
{
  forall(j in M) sum(i in N) A[i,j]*x[i]>=B[j];
}
```

and then you can you write logical constraints:

```
int n=3;
int m=4;

range N=1..n;
range M=1..m;

float A[N][M]=[[1,4,9,6],[8,5,0,8],[2,9,0,2]];
float B[M]=[3,1,3,0];
float C[N]=[1,1,1];

{int} efficiencySet={1,2};


dvar boolean activeEfficiencySet;
dvar boolean x[N];

minimize sum(i in N) C[i]*x[i]*(1-0.1*activeEfficiencySet*(i not in efficiencySet));

subject to
{
  forall(j in M) sum(i in N) A[i,j]*x[i]>=B[j];
  
  activeEfficiencySet==(1<=sum(i in efficiencySet) x[i]);
}
```

Comment: I made the mistake of not mentioning that I'm using the Python API with docplex to model this LP.  Being new to both CPLEX and programming in general, the syntax involved in converting your OPL logic to Python API format often trips me up, but I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the help, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alex's data, I have written the program in docplex (cplex python API)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

n = 3
m = 4


A = {}
A[0, 0] = 1
A[0, 1] = 4
A[0, 2] = 9
A[0, 3] = 6
A[1, 0] = 8
A[1, 1] = 5
A[1, 2] = 0
A[1, 3] = 8
A[2, 0] = 2
A[2, 1] = 9
A[2, 2] = 0
A[2, 3] = 2

B = {}
B[0] = 3
B[1] = 1
B[2] = 3
B[3] = 0

C = {}
C[0] = 1
C[1] = 1
C[2] = 1

efficiencySet = [0, 1]

mdl = Model(name="")

activeEfficiencySet = mdl.binary_var()
x = mdl.binary_var_dict(range(n), name="x")

# constraint 1:
for j in range(m):
    mdl.add_constraint(mdl.sum(A[i, j] * x[i] for i in range(n)) >= B[j])

# constraint 2:
mdl.add(activeEfficiencySet == (mdl.sum(x) >= 1))

# objective function:
# expr = mdl.linear_expr()
lst = []
for i in range(n):
    if i not in efficiencySet:
        lst.append((C[i] * x[i] * (1 - 0.1 * activeEfficiencySet)))
    else:
        lst.append(C[i] * x[i])

mdl.minimize(mdl.sum(lst))

mdl.solve()

for i in range(n):
    print(str(x[i]) + " : " + str(x[i].solution_value))

activeEfficiencySet.solution_value
```